# VIEWS Filter AND/OR | Cannot change to "AND" | Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, in views filter, i cannot change "OR" for "AND". Nothing append when I change "or" for "and". Someone have the same problem ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have AND and OR operators together on the same level. Rearrange query conditions as follows:

[image]